# Retrieving email config

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

Can you tell me how to retrieve email config values (as set up in Config/email.php)? The documentation appears to tell me how to load or set values when creating the CakeEmail object, but I just want to display to the user default values like the "from" address BEFORE they override them or send the email.

Answer (score 1):

You've got a couple of options. You can either get all the email config and extract the bits you need from that using `CakeEmail::config()` or extract just the bit you need, for example the from email using `CakeEmail::from()`:-

```
<?php

$Email = new CakeEmail('default');

// Get all the email config
$config = $Email->config();
debug($config['from']);

// Get just the 'from' email config
$from = $Email->from();
debug($from);
```

Comment: Thankyou for that, sir. Makes more sense now. Slightly unhelpful of the "book" documentation not to make it clear that many of the methods have both a "setter" and "getter" functionality.

Answer (score 0):

OK - I think I have stumbled on the answer; CakeEmail has a (public) "from()" method which returns the (protected) "from" property - this is covered in the "API" documentation, but not in the "book" documentation.